# Cross referencing structs in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference

Is there a way to create two structs that make a reference to each other?
Example:

```
struct str1
{
  struct str1* ptr1;
  struct str2* ptr2;
}

struct str2
{
  struct str1* ptr1;
  struct str2* ptr2;
}
```

Comment: jsut add a forward reference:  put `struct str2;` at the top.

Comment: It may help to think of structs and functions in terms of variables. A struct is just a variable that contains more variables, and a function is just a variable that can act upon itself. With that in mind, you just declare what you want to use before you use it, even if you have yet to define it, just like any other variable, and you'll be fine.

Comment: yes, it was wrong, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct str2; // put a forward reference to str2 here

struct str1
{
  struct str1* s1;
  struct str2* s2;
};

struct str2
{
  struct str1* s1;
  struct str2* s2;
};

int main()
{
  struct str1 s1;
  struct str2 s2;

  s1.s1 = &s1;
  s1.s2 = &s2;
  s2.s1 = &s1;
  s2.s2 = &s2;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct str1 str1_t;
typedef struct str2 str2_t;
struct str1
{
  str2_t *user1;
  str2_t *user2;
}

struct str2
{
   str1_t *user1;
   str1_t *user2;
}
```