# How to make cross pointers in structs

Tags: c, list, graph-databases

So here's my problem, I want to create a graph-database. My concept idea is a node (which will be of type "Vrtc" in the code. It will cointain an (int) id, a (char*) string (called "str") and a list (l_est) of paths in and out.
The list will contain an "array" of pointers to nodes, the amount of nodes in the list, and the maximum number of nodes.

```
typedef struct Vrtc
{
    int id;
    char *str;
    l_est *pathsIn;
    l_est *pathsOut;
} Vrtc;

typedef struct l_est{
    Vrtc **Vert;
    int qtdElem;
    int maxElem;
} l_est;
```

As you may know, there'll be a problem of "Unknow type/Type undeclared inside the node. I was hoping anyone could give a tip of how to do it, if it is possible.

Comment: My hint: google "C forward declaration". This is what is needed here: insert `struct l_est;` as 1st line and use `struct l_est *pathsIn, pathsOut;` in `struct Vrtc`.

Comment: I would change the title to "How to use a struct before it is defined" or "How to make cross pointers in structs". Btw. I found: [SO: Cross referencing structs in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341335/cross-referencing-structs-in-c).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross referencing structs in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341335/cross-referencing-structs-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [**forward declaration**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration):

```
typedef struct l_est l_est;

typedef struct {
  int id;
  char *str;
  l_est *pathsIn, *pathsOut;
} Vrtc;

typedef struct l_est {
  Vrtc **Vert;
  int qtdElem, maxElem;
} l_est;
```

The first type definition of `struct l_est` is a so-called "incomplete type". This type may *not be* used for variables or with `sizeof` but it *may* be used to declare pointer.

The incomplete type may later be overridden by a "complete type" without complaints of the compiler.

Similar solutions can be found in other languages (e.g. Pascal).